# RxJava Flowable<List<T>> do operation on each item and then do operation on resulted list

Tags: android, rx-java, iterable, flatmap, concatmap

I have a `Flowable<List<Item>>` for which I want to :

1. Make an operation on each item
2. After that, I want to make an operation on the whole resulted list.

This is not working now because it looks like is entering in an infinite loop::

```
        return list.concatMap(list ->
                    Observable.fromIterable(list)
                            .map(item -> {
                                item.setValue(value);
                                return item;
                            }).toList().toFlowable()
                            .flatMap(updatedList -> mLocalDataSource.update(updatedList)))
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

Comment: Hmm, the code you have here doesn't look like it would enter an infinite loop. You could change a few operators (`flatMapIterable(l -> l)` instead of `concatMap(l -> Observable.fromIterable(...)`, `doOnNext` instead of `map`, `flatMapPublisher` instead of `toFlowable().flatMap(...)`), but what you have there should work. I do agree with @PPartisan, though - just iterating over the list, rather than flattening it/rebuilding it via RxJava operators, is a better choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's any advantage over just doing this work in the `flatMap()`/`concatMap()`. All I'd say is that it would be cleaner if `Item` were immutable.

```
list.concatMap(items -> {
  for(Item item : items)
    item.setValue(value);
  return mLocalDataSource.update(items)
});
```

Comment: But this requires N api level, cannot I do it with Rx to avoid setting the N api level conditioning statement?

Comment: Yeah can just use a regular for loop, I'll update my answer

Comment: I appreciate your approach, but I exptected to somehow do it with rxjava

Comment: You could do it all with RxJava, but in my opinion it would be more code and less clarity